# GINPUT with MATLAB AppDesigner

Tags: matlab, input, callback

I'm building an app in AppDesigner and I would like to access points on the axes I create and use those points to run some code. I've tried buttondownfcn but it is not supported.

I've been trying ginput but can't get it to work.

my code is like this:

ginput(app.UIAxes,1)

where I want to ask the user to select one point on the axes.

Is this another compatibility issue?

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is [not currently supported](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/graphics-support-in-app-designer.html) by the `UIAxes` class.